# URL for Mapbox style sheet JSON

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

Is there a URL that serves up the style sheet JSON for a given style? All the URL's are in Mapbox scheme:

```
mapbox://styles/wfisher/41dj33random72ravc31c5dyn
```

But I'd like to download the JSON directly on load so I can modify it before passing in a Javascript object to `<ReactMapGL>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the Mapbox Static API:

https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#retrieve-a-style

so the URL would be:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/wfisher/41dj33random72ravc31c5dyn?access_token=<token>
```

and the sever will compress it if you use `Accept-Encoding`, too.